# Providing new version for edit I rejected?

Tags: support

This edit:

https://iota.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/123

I rejected, because it changed the meaning of the first paragraph, while most of the other parts are really useful typo corrections. I expected to be able to edit it later again (that's why I bookmarked it) and provide a suggested edit that fixes the typos but does not change the first paragraph. However, whenever I click edit, I get back to my rejected edit and cannot do anything about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited it to reflect the typo changes. Not sure what the issue with it blocking your edit is though.

Comment: thank you very much :)